# How to use mapDispatchToProps

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am learning Redux React. How to use mapDispatchToProps ? My code is like below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getAddress } from '../store/actions/addressActions';

class Dashboard extends Component {
    componentDidMount = () => {
        this.props.getAddress();
    };

    render() {
        return <div>Hello { console.log(this.props) } </div>;
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    address: state.address
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    getAddress
});

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Dashboard);
```

I am getting console output like below

[image]

Where I am doing mistake ?  How to use mapDispatchToProps properly ?

Comment: It is hard to reason what `getAddress` action does without seeing the code. Should it obtain address and put it into the state ? Problem can be there.

Comment: Thanks @dev-null for your reply. Here is the addressAction. `import Axios from 'axios';

export const getAddress = () => dispatch => {
  return Axios.get('/api/address')
  .then(response => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'getAddresses',
      payload: response.data
    });
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
}

export default { getAddress };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you define `mapDispatchToProps` as an `object` or you return the dispatched function from `mapDispatchToProps` instead of an object

Using first approach your mapStateToProps will look like

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
    getAddress
};
```

Using second approach it would look like

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    getAddress: (...args) => dispatch(getAddress(...args));
});
```

Also since you are using `combineReducers` you need to change how you access the state in `mapStateToProps`

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ address: state.addressReducer.address });
```

Comment: Thanks @Shubham Khatri for your solution. But your solution is not working.

Comment: Since you call action creator in componentDidMount, address will initially be undefined, but later should return you the correct value you are access the state correctly. Are you using combineReducers in your code. Also what the reducer which updates address look like

Comment: Yes, I am using combineReducers like this `const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  authReducer,
  addressReducer
});`. What is the solution ?

Comment: Your mapStateToProps must be `const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    address: state.addressReducer.address
});` . then in addition to the above change in mapDispatchToProps

Comment: Thank you @Shubham Khatri. Your solution is working. But I am getting value twice.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuC46.png.

Comment: @abuabu As I said earlier, since you dispatch an action in componentDidMount, for the first render, address will contain the initial value in reducer and once the data is updated, the updated value will be visible

Comment: Thanks @Shubham Khatri, What should I do to get Data once ?

Comment: Inside the render method, `return null` is addresses field is not of the specified type

Comment: Thanks @Shubham Khatri. Could you please explain a bit more ? My render is like below `render() {
    return <div>Hello {console.log(this.props)}</div>;
  }`.

Comment: You would write `render() {
    if(Object.keys(this.props.address) === 0) { return null}
    return <div>Hello {console.log(this.props)}</div>;
}`

Comment: Thanks @Shubham Khatri. Is it the only way to avoid Double data ? Actually I am redirecting user to dashboard after login. In this regard is it possible to call this action after login to avoid double data?

Comment: I would say getting data twice is not an issue and is perfectly a normal scenario

Comment: Thanks @Shubham Khatri. Ha ha ha. I am still getting double data using your code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think, initially in `store` the `address` is `undefined`. correct?  and the getAddress action will set the address value.

Here is what you missed,
1) you have dispatch the action. you can use any of following

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    getAddress: (...args) => dispatch(getAddress(...args));
});
```

or

```
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";

    const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({getAddress}, dispatch)
```

Comment: Thanks @Harish for your solution. But your solution is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your should update `mapDispatchToProps` method a little bit. In addition, you should export it to writing test.

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

export const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  actions: bindActionCreators(
    getAddress,
    dispatch,
  ),
})
```

Comment: Thanks @Vu Luu for your solution. But your solution is not working.